# Running Selenium webdriver scripts in android device (Samsung galaxy tab)-Portrait mode

Tags: automated-testing, webdriver, selenium2, android, mobile

I have been stuck in an issue while running selenium webdriver script in android device -Portrait mode.
Script is running successfully in landscape mode but when we run the same script in android device keeping device in portrait mode script is failing for few actions like clicking the link, even though object locator remains same.

Script is like below:

```
@Test
public void testUntitled() throws Exception {
    driver.get("application uRl");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[2]/li[2]/a/div")).click();

 //below line throws exception
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("<css selector>")).click();
}
```

Note: First two statements execute successfully in portrait mode. However the third statement `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("<css selector>")).click();` fails (in portrait mode) and throws the below exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: This WebElement is not visisble and may not be clicked.
Build info: version: &apos;unknown&apos;, revision: &apos;unknown&apos;, time: &apos;unknown&apos;
System info: os.name: &apos;Linux&apos;, os.arch: &apos;armv7l&apos;, os.version: &apos;2.6.36.3&apos;, java.version: &apos;0&apos;
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Command duration or timeout: 322 milliseconds
Build info: version: &apos;2.32.0&apos;, revision: &apos;6c40c18&apos;, time: &apos;2013-04-09 17:22:56&apos;
System info: os.name: &apos;Windows 7&apos;, os.arch: &apos;x86&apos;, os.version: &apos;6.1&apos;, java.version: &apos;1.7.0_40&apos;
Session ID: 1385108177533
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities [{platform=ANDROID, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserName=android, browserConnectionEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=true, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, webdriver.remote.sessionid=1385108177533, takesScreenshot=true, version=13}]
```

Please suggest how this issue can be resolved. Is there any settings to be done for running script in portrait mode?

Comment: Does `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[2]/li[2]/a/div")).click();` bring up new element `<css selector>` without loading the page?

Comment: No... On performing this action driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[2]/li[2]/a/div")).click(); , new page loads. In the newly loaded page need to click header link. Same action is passing in landscape mode but failing in portrait mode.

Comment: looking at the error `This WebElement is not visisble and may not be clicked.` are you able to click on element manually in portrait mode?

Comment: Yes , manually I am able to click and the link is visible. For running tests in Portrait mode, Is there any settings need to be done?

Answer (score 1):

Try to scroll to an element first, and then click.

Here are few solutions for scrolling to element:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/20487332
- https://github.com/BlackPepperSoftware/bp-support-selenium/blob/master/src/main/java/uk/co/blackpepper/support/selenium/WebElementUtils.java#L53

Comment: You need to provide more information than simply linking to other sites for your responses to be helpful, particularly when you are answering questions as old as this one.

Comment: @Dmitry Cheremushkin the second link when clicked on says "page not found"